# Storing JSON in an ASP.NET literal using C# and accessing it using JavaScript throws a "invalid character" error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying to store a JSON string inside an ASP.NET Literal Control. This JSON string is in this format:

```
[
    ['Time', 'Speed', 'Distance'],
    ['09-07-2015 2:21:39 PM', 76, 500],
    ['08-07-2015 6:02:41 PM', 350, 500],
    ['08-07-2015 5:55:43 PM', 10, 50],
    ['08-07-2015 5:55:36 PM', 50, 50],
    ['08-07-2015 5:55:21 PM', 180, 80],
    ['08-07-2015 5:51:38 PM', 100, null]
]
```

This is how I am adding it to literal:

```
Literal1.Text = "<input type='hidden' id='jsondata' value=\"" + JSONData + "\" />";
```

But actual JSON data that will be entered by the user may contain any character including `"` and `'`. And this JSON data is accessed inside JavaScript like:

```
function SetGraphData() {
    var hiddenField = $('#jsondata');
    jsonData = $.parseJSON(hiddenField.val());
}
```

But when parsing JSON, it's showing me `Invalid character` error. Please tell me what can be the reason?

Comment: JSON strings must be quoted with double-quote characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Also you should make sure to properly HTML escape your JSON data using something like [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx), or since you're using ASP.NET, just use `<asp:HiddenField>` instead of your current contraption.

Comment: Thanks. I used `HtmlEncode` and replaced single quotes with double quotes. It's working now. :)